# Changing the response for the JWT User Data result

Tags: laravel, jwt, laravel-7

I am developing an API using Laravel 7 and L5-Swagger for API documentation. When I try to get the user information with an invalid token, I want the the result to be {"error": "Unauthorized"} but it returns

> Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\RouteNotFoundException: Route [login] not defined.

Despite that the login functionality works fine.

This is my auth routes

```
 Route::group([
'middleware' => 'api',
'prefix' => 'auth'
 ], function ($router) {
   Route::post('register', 'AuthController@register');
   Route::post('login', 'AuthController@login');
   Route::post('logout', 'AuthController@logout');
   Route::post('refresh', 'AuthController@refresh');
   Route::post('user', 'AuthController@user');
});
```

How to get it to display Unauthorized response?

Comment: Are you performing POST request?

Comment: yes, I am using post request in the swagger UI